# On which types of data types/ objects can you do a Linq join?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm trying to left join two string[*,*] 2 d arrays in Linq. I'm receiving the below error

"could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'string[*,*]'. 'Join' not found."

All of my research on joining strings only yielded info on concats, not joins.

So I converted to a dataTable and tried to do a join, still got the same error.

Logically then I researched what types of data types can you run a Linq join on and I could not find any direction.

What am I doing wrong guys? I have 2 datasets in memory that I need to join.

Comment: You should post your current code

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays do not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you cannot use most Linq methods with it unless you use `Cast<T>()` first.